# Cart Page Redirect to Customer Login Page

Tags: cart, magento2.2.4

When Click on **View and Edit cart button** from Mini-cart,

> It will redirect to checkout/cart page. And sometimes after 1 second
>   it will automatically redirect to customer/account/login.

When i try to debug more with it, i found one ajax call gives me 401 status code & i found one js file in vendor in that written code like if status code 401 comes then it will redirect to login page.

> Js File :
>   vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/error-processor.js

Please find attached image of Console. [image]

Can any one explain me, why it gives 401 response status code?

Comment: I was getting same issue before and fixed it by changes on js file but I don't know why it gives 401 response status code, please check my ans if you want to fix that issue.

Comment: ok, Thanks for your replay dear. But i want to fix the issue not want to bend it.